# Predicting whether NaOH will react or not

Tags: organic-chemistry

I recently came across a problem which made use of the fact that NaOH doesn't react with benzyl alcohol

The problem was of a past year paper of an engineering exam in my country which I had attempted incorrectly.

Although now that i know that the pka value of benzyl alcohol,i know that the reaction won't take place to a large extent,but as an examinee who wasn't aware of the pka value,is there any method to decode whether the reaction takes place or not(or any such reaction mechanism for the same)??, as the acidic hydrogen tempts us to treat it as an acid.

Comment: Are you asking, "how could I know from the structure of benzyl alcohol that it will form an alkoxide in presence of NaOH?"? Because as it stands it's not really clear what you are asking. I can flip this around: if you did know that it forms an alkoxide readily, would you have predicted that it reacts?

Answer (score 1):

It is good that you understand the role of the $\mathrm{pK_a}$ to decide whether an acid/base reaction can occur or not.

I am not aware of an *absolute* way to determine, just by looking at the structure, what the $\mathrm{pK_a}$ value would be. There's two things, however, that might be of help:

1. If you learn the approximate $\mathrm{pK_a}$ value of some compounds (or just whether they react with NaOH I guess), then if you are faced with a similar compound, you might be able to tell whether it is a stronger or a weaker acid than the ones you know, and that might help you place the molecule on your mental scale.
2. If not in an exam situation, then you should be aware that the $\mathrm{pK_a}$ values are very often found in organic chemistry tables [(example)](https://organicchemistrydata.org/hansreich/resources/pka/). Using this tables then, you will be able to at least get a $\mathrm{pK_a}$ value for an unsubstitued compound, and you only need to consider the electronic (or sometimes steric) modification of the substituents.

As for how you could've known the $\mathrm{pK_a}$ value of benzyl alcohol, consider the following way of thinking: the methyl group connecting the phenyl and the hydroxyl group sort of acts as an insulator between the two functional groups, making benzyl alcohol more similar to ethanol than to phenol - indeed the $\mathrm{pK_a}$ of ethanol and benzyl alcohol are quite close. Then you need to know that ethanol does not react with NaOH (this was probably covered in your class, so  you might know this, see point 1. above), and then you can conclude than benzyl alcohol won't react either

Comment: Technically sodium hydroxide [does react with ethanol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_ethoxide), although sodium metal offers better conversion to form the sodium ethoxide product.

Comment: This is a bit surprising - it might be that you can *make* them react under extreme conditions, but I'm pretty sure they won't react if you mix them together. In fact, you can even [buy sodium hydroxide dissolved in ethanol](https://itwreagents.com/italy/en/product/l-0-1n-in-ethanol-volumetric-solution/182284).

Comment: Maybe the the extreme condition is the ethanol must be anhydrous. Likely the commercial product contains some sodium ethoxide, which would not really affect its acid-base reactivity.

Comment: Hydroxide, water and alcohols establish equilibria among the various alkoxides etc. depending on solvent and original oxide concentrations.